# This Code for Color Shading of Text Works with Pdflatex but Not Xelatex

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, pdftex, color, shading

Consider

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{scalerel} % For Vertical/Horizontal Stretch of Letters

\usepackage{pbsi} % for bsifamily font.


\newcommand\titleshading[3]{
    \newcommand\xoffset{0.3}
    \newcommand\yoffset{-0.25}
    % Blur
    \foreach \x in {-0.1,0.1} {
        \foreach \y in {-0.1,0.1} {         
            \node[blue!65!white] at (#1em+\xoffset em+\x em,#2em+\yoffset em+\y em) {
                \scalebox{2.5}{\Huge\bsifamily{#3}} 
            };
        }
    }

    % Main Shadow
    \node[blue!40!white] at (#1em+0.3em,#2em-0.2em) {
        \scalebox{2.5}{\Huge\bsifamily{#3}} 
    };
    \node[red] at (#1em,#2em) {% <-- here put the color you like 
        \scalebox{2.5}{\Huge\bsifamily{#3}} 
    };
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]   
    \titleshading{15}{0}{With Pdflatex}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

But when I try to compile the code with Xelatex, I get

[image]

QUESTION: Is there anything I can do to get this code to compile with Xelatex? (Ironically, the actual code I need this for does not work with Pdflatex.)

Thank you.

Comment: (if you get the code from somewhere you may want to cite the source.)

Comment: It works with lualatex.

Comment: This was happened because of `pbsi.sty`, may I know for what purpose you used this package?

Comment: you get a quite clear error on the terminal: `xdvipdfmx:fatal: Sorry, pfa format not supported; please convert the font to pfb, e.g., with t1binary.` Your font doesn't work with xelatex.

Comment: I also get `Package pbsi Warning: bad encoding; assuming T1..` which points to an issue with this package. WIthout it, it works like a charm (except for another error due to an undefined macro related to this package). So it is really a font issue.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Thank you. I guess I'll have select another font.

Comment: @Jasper Habicht Thank you for looking into this. I'll have to choose a different font.

Comment: @Simon Dispa  Many thanks. I did not know that. I will have to check if my document, which produces a special page for another document, also compiles with lualatex. Thanks again.

Comment: @Simon Dispa Unfortunately, my other document does not compile with `lualatex` seemingly (as I just found out) because  it contains some `psvectorian` commands. But thanks again for the previous information.